# How to configure an Existed downloaded Orchard CMS (MVC 4.0) site on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have been searching for the relevent tutorials for that but could not find a satisfactory one for that purpose... I have downloaded an existing Orchard CMS (MVC 4.0) site from bitbucket.. and wants to configure that on the localhost... i have downloaded the new orchard and configure it with the it with the database of the project which is in SQLServer 2008 R2... i have established a connection of the database with the application... but as i run that application in the browser, it gives me an error of "Resource not found"... i am using Microsoft WebMatrix for this purpose...

Looking forward for a positive reply... Thanks in advance